# Print via AirPrint with preselected printer

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, airprint

I want to print something via AirPrint but it should be automated. I want something like a selector in the settings where the user selects the printer he wants to use for this session.
After that, at a specific moment, the iPhone should interact with the printer without popping up die printing dialog every time.
Is this possible? If yes, how can I achieve it and is it App-Store safe?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The questions was asked before, thanks for the advice! But it was back in 2011. 3 years are some long time in this topic. Doesn't something changed?

Comment: Nothing has changed in AirPrint. There are printers available, such as PoS and label printers that provide their own iOS libraries that print directly via Bluetooth or WiFi. These don't use AirPrint

Comment: Ok thanks! I think I have some luck, the Brother printer I want to use has an own SDK :)